# How does flexbox work when its children are fullscreen

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I want to make a horizontal scrolling website
So I used the following

```html
 <div class="flexParent">
        <div class="flexChild"></div>
        <div class="flexChild"></div>
 </div>
```

```css
.flexParent {
  display: flex;
}

.flexChild {
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
}
```

But this causes the screen to divide in two parts and each div getting a 50vw.
But if I change `.flexParent` to

```css
.flexParent { 
  display: flex; 
  flex-direction: column
  overflow-x: scroll
}
```

then the other div is rendered on the next page, each child retaining the 100vh and 100vw height and width respectively, requiring me to scroll down.
Why does this not happen in `flex-direction: row`

js fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/oenkraLt/16/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need set the width via [`flex-basis`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-basis) and also define the [`flex-shrink`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-shrink) to be zero. This can be done using the [`flex`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex) shorthand that also sets the [`flex-grow`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/flex-grow). So, declare `flex: 0 0 100%;`

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.flexParent {
  display: flex;
  column-gap: 1px;
}

.flexChild {
  flex: 0 0 100%;
  height: 98vh;
  background-color: lightblue;
}
```

```html
<div class="flexParent">
  <div class="flexChild">Some content 1</div>
  <div class="flexChild">Some content 2</div>
</div>
```

Comment: cheers, thank you that answers most of my question. Do you also know why the two examples behave differently? is it because HTML by default places elements from top to bottom?